# Android Studio install on CentOS 7

Tags: java, linux, android-studio, centos

I have tried for some months mow to get Android Studio 2.2.3 to work on my CentOS 7 machine. I get the splash screen alright, with the "progress bar" under the "Powered by the intellij platform" full. But never past that. In my shell, it seems to eventually boil down to this:

```
`File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded`.
```

I checked other asked questions, and manually created the directory /root/.ancroid but that didn't help. It appears that android studio is not fetching from the right directory, so I installed the dependency libraries, installed the Oracle JDK (though OpenJDK still seems to be in use) `sudo`d, `chmod`ed, I even tried to examine the studio.sh shell script. You might refer to me as an intermediate android developer, but I'm relatively new to linux. Don;t know if installing android studio on an Ubuntu VM is a better option.
Pls, any answers will be appreciated. 
If it's any help, I'm on an hp *ProLiant* Machine. The actual stream of persistent errors are shown below:

```
sh studio.sh    
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@6d5380c2 for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/usr/local/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Trying /root/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/tmp/jna7335844113788285502.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /root/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/tmp/jna7335844113788285502.tmp
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.lazilyLoadDesktopProperty(XToolkit.java:1541)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDesktopProperty(Toolkit.java:1803)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.load(DragSource.java:131)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.<clinit>(DragSource.java:148)
    at com.intellij.ide.dnd.DnDManagerImpl.registerSource(DnDManagerImpl.java:98)
    at com.intellij.ide.dnd.DnDSupport.<init>(DnDSupport.java:70)
    at com.intellij.ide.dnd.DnDSupport.<init>(DnDSupport.java:32)
    at com.intellij.ide.dnd.DnDSupport$1.install(DnDSupport.java:276)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorGutterComponentImpl.installDnD(EditorGutterComponentImpl.java:230)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorGutterComponentImpl.<init>(EditorGutterComponentImpl.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.<init>(EditorImpl.java:560)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorFactoryImpl.createEditor(EditorFactoryImpl.java:193)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorFactoryImpl.createViewer(EditorFactoryImpl.java:174)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConsoleViewUtil.setupConsoleEditor(ConsoleViewUtil.java:63)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.ProgressStep.<init>(ProgressStep.java:59)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.ConsolidatedProgressStep.<init>(ConsolidatedProgressStep.java:38)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizard$FirstRunProgressStep.<init>(FirstRunWizard.java:143)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:62)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:99)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:91)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrame.<init>(FlatWelcomeFrame.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrameProvider.createFrame(FlatWelcomeFrameProvider.java:29)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:171)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:340)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:200)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.awt.AWTException: Exception: class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero occurred while creating cursor CopyDrop.32x32
    at java.awt.Cursor.getSystemCustomCursor(Cursor.java:363)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.lazilyLoadDesktopProperty(XToolkit.java:1539)
    ... 40 more
[  15175]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.intellij.ide.dnd.DnDManagerImpl.registerSource(DnDManagerImpl.java:98)
    at com.intellij.ide.dnd.DnDSupport.<init>(DnDSupport.java:70)
    at com.intellij.ide.dnd.DnDSupport.<init>(DnDSupport.java:32)
    at com.intellij.ide.dnd.DnDSupport$1.install(DnDSupport.java:276)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorGutterComponentImpl.installDnD(EditorGutterComponentImpl.java:230)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorGutterComponentImpl.<init>(EditorGutterComponentImpl.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.<init>(EditorImpl.java:560)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorFactoryImpl.createEditor(EditorFactoryImpl.java:193)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorFactoryImpl.createViewer(EditorFactoryImpl.java:174)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConsoleViewUtil.setupConsoleEditor(ConsoleViewUtil.java:63)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.ProgressStep.<init>(ProgressStep.java:59)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.ConsolidatedProgressStep.<init>(ConsolidatedProgressStep.java:38)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizard$FirstRunProgressStep.<init>(FirstRunWizard.java:143)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:62)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:99)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:91)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrame.<init>(FlatWelcomeFrame.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrameProvider.createFrame(FlatWelcomeFrameProvider.java:29)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:171)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:340)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:200)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to load system cursor: DnD.Cursor.CopyDrop : cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.load(DragSource.java:135)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.<clinit>(DragSource.java:148)
    ... 37 more
[  15179]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 2.2.3  Build #AI-145.3537739 
[  15179]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_76-release 
[  15179]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
[  15179]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
[  15179]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 
[  15179]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:  
[  16081]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
[  18713]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/StudioDownloaderaddon2-1.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: First execute `chmod -R 777 path/to/studio.sh` and hit enter. After that use `./studio.sh`

Comment: Thanks. It's still giving the same set of errors.

Comment: It probably doesn't help much, but this seems like a related bug report (although not CentOS): https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-mir/+bug/1250613